# Send Notification to multiple devices token

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, token

Want to send Notification to multiple devices token which are stored in firebase realtime database
[Here is my realtime database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSnmZ.png)

I did a code

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference tokensRef = database.getReference("users").child("token");

// Query for all tokens
tokensRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<String> tokensList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String token = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            tokensList.add(token);
        }
        
        // Build notification data
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("title", "Notification Title");
        data.put("body", "Notification Body");
        
        // Build and send notification to all tokens
        FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
        for (String token : tokensList) {
            RemoteMessage message = new RemoteMessage.Builder(token)
                    .setData(data)
                    .build();
            try {
                messaging.send(message);
            } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error sending message to " + token, e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Database error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: The Message class is inside the Firebase admin sdk but you cannot use that in your android project, you can only use firebase admin sdk in the server side and then you will be able to use the Message class.

Comment: Create a topic, let each user subscribe to that topic.. and then post the notification to that specific topic. Firebase DocLink [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging]

Comment: Since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA) will help.